# How to create circle with timer on UI which support all IE browsers

Tags: html, css, user-interface, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

How to create circle with timer on UI which support all IE browsers

I was able to achieve svg and circle tags but the same changes are not working on IE8 and lower browsers.[image: IE8]

Comment: Wow, IE7. Incredible. Anyway, is a simple fallback with a text-only counter in JavaScript OK, or does it need to be the animated circle?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you want to support old versions of an IE browser. like IE 7, IE 8, etc.

I want to inform you that [SVG](https://caniuse.com/#feat=svg) is supported by IE version 9.

From IE 9 to IE 11, all the versions of the IE browser has partial support for SVG.

> - Partial support in IE9-11 refers to not supporting animations.
> - IE9-11 & Edge don't properly scale SVG files.

So it is difficult to create an animated timer for those old versions of an IE browser.

I suggest you can try to display a simple timer for unsupported versions of the IE browser and you can display the animated circle timer for the supported versions of the IE browser(like Ie 11).

Here is a simple example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML Timer example</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}
    #demo {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background: red;
      border-radius: 50%;
     vertical-align: middle;
     line-height: 100px; 
 border:solid black;
    }
  
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.innerHTML = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * 5,
        display = document.getElementById('demo');
    startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Below is another helpful link but that solution may also cause the issues with the older version of the IE browser. So it is better to use the simple timer.

[CSS Pie Timer](https://css-tricks.com/css-pie-timer/)